# Position image under div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I having trouble position the image under the sidebar div 
[What it looks like](https://unsee.cc/nopamegu/)

[What it needs to look like](https://unsee.cc/pitosage/)

I'm unsure weather i need to use a float, position, etc.
Sorry for the stupid noob question but I just can't nut it out.

Thanks in advance.

```css
#outer {
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(127, 127, 255);
  padding: 5px;
}
#inner {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border-style: outset;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(191, 233, 191);
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
#image {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <h1> The Chandra space-based X-Ray Observatory</h1>

  <div id="inner">
    <a href="http://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/black-holes/">Nearby black hole</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/07-139.html" />'Death Star' Galaxy Black Hole</a>
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/content/black-holes-have-simple-feeding-habits/">Black Holes feeding</a>
    <br>
    <a href="https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/nustar/tale-of-two-black-holes/">Two Black Holes</a>
    </br>
  </div>

  <div id="image">
    <img src="binary.jpg" alt="Binary" style="width:226px;height:170px;">
  </div>

  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The “What it needs to look like” image is already gone. Also, why did you split up the CSS and HTML into two seperate code snippets?

Comment: Can't see what you want it to look like. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place  paragraph tag and content

Lorem Ipsum text

before the image & in image css.
add `clear:both`. Hope this is the one you are looking for.if not let me know.

Comment: No my only problem is floating the lorem ipsum text to the right of the image and nav bar.

http://postimg.org/image/we8albm6h/

Comment: Replace the position of <p> </p> tag above the image. Currently it is after image. So when you use clear:both it is clearing after image and the below data will break down to new line.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/k6v1g2g0t/6076cfb0/

This is the outcome of positioning the paragraph before the image.
It positions the sample text between the div and the image instead of to the space right of the div & image.

Sorry to hassle you with the questions.

Comment: In your html at second tag . double quotes isn't in proper position. Update that and check it once.  <a href="http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/07-139.html /">'Death Star' Galaxy Black Hole</a>

Comment: Same outcome after fixing double quotes